# run js after ajax content load

Tags: javascript, ajax

I now this question have been asked, but i am totally ignorance in the subject, and i can't really use the answers. I made every script of my page with tutorials, but i failed.
My problem: I have a section where I load content from external html with ajax (used this tut: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmfZp4iFzOs), and I have to run a js after every time I loaded a content. But the script doesn't work, because it is running before I load the content.

The html (for example):

```
<body>    
    <ul>
        <li><a class="menu" href="1.html">1</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="2.html">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="3.html">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content_area"></div>
    <script src="menu.js"></script>
</body>
```

The menu.js:

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content_area').hide().load(href).fadeIn('normal');
    return false;
});
```

The external html is complicate but i have to run this script every time, when clicked (and loaded) a menu:

```
var init = function() {
  var box1 = document.querySelector('.container1').children[0],
      showPanelButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#show-buttons button'),
      panelClassName = 'show-front',

      onButtonClick = function( event ){
        box1.removeClassName( panelClassName );
        panelClassName = event.target.className;
        box1.addClassName( panelClassName );
      };

  for (var i=0, len = showPanelButtons.length; i < len; i++) {
    showPanelButtons[i].addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClick, false);
  }

  document.getElementById('toggle-backface-visibility').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    box1.toggleClassName('panels-backface-invisible');
  }, false);

};

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Sorry for my bad english. Please help me! Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are using jQuery, but in a very limited fashion. Is there a reason other than just being new to it that you aren't using jQuery's promise structure to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.load()` function is an asynchronous operation, so it's going to "return" before it completes.  Thus, instead of waiting for it to return, you supply it with a "callback" function which it will invoke when it completes.  Something like this:

```
$('#content_area').hide().load(href, function () {
    init();
    $('#content_area').fadeIn('normal');
});
```

Note a couple of things here:

1. I've moved the `.fadeIn()` call to within the callback as well, since you don't want to fade in the element until after its content is loaded.
2. Both calls are wrapped within a single nameless (anonymous) `function () {}`.  This function is itself a value which is passed to the `.load()` function and will be invoked when `.load()` has completed its work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your explanation but unfortunately I don't understand exatly which part i have to change the code. I'm designer not developer, so all of this is chinese for me. Can you give me exact instructions?

Comment: @user3829341: Essentially it replaces the line: `$('#content_area').hide().load(href).fadeIn('normal');`  It's not clear to me if `init()` needs to happen before or after the `.fadeIn()`, so those can be re-arranged.  Note that things like `.fadeIn()` are *also* asynchronous and have their own callback functions, so you can wrap even more code in another anonymous function and pass it to that.  Any other code which needs to execute when those operations complete can be placed within those anonymous functions.

Comment: Thanks you very much! Finally it's working with your help! This was the last problem in my site.
Just a little thing: the fade in is ok. But can i make a fade out when i click another element?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', init, false); ", you can use a callback with jquery load()'s function.

```
$('#content_area').hide().load(href, init).fadeIn('normal');
```

Comment: Thanks you! I tried but i get the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: href is not defined